# Telerik RadTreeList: GetDataKeyValues returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I am trying to get a client data key value in my rad tree list, but it always returns null:

```
private List<xItems> GetTreeListChanges()
{
    List<xItems> xItems = new List<xItems>();
    foreach(TreeListDataItem rtlItem in rtlxItems.Items)
    {
        string xItemsId = Convert.ToString(rtlItem.GetDataKeyValue("xItemsId"));
    }
    [...]
}
```

Here is the markup code, where my data key is well defined:

```
<telerik:RadTreeList ID="rtlxItems" runat="server" AllowMultiItemEdit="false"
        ParentDataKeyNames="ParentId" DataKeyNames="ChlidId" ClientDataKeyNames="xItemsId">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XItemsId is a clientside datakey only, you should change the getDataKey to use ChildId (you also have a typo in the dataKeyNames declaration

```
private List<xItems> GetTreeListChanges()
{
    List<xItems> xItems = new List<xItems>();
    foreach(TreeListDataItem rtlItem in rtlxItems.Items)
    {
        string xItemsId = Convert.ToString(rtlItem.GetDataKeyValue("ChildId"));
    }
    [...]
} 

<telerik:RadTreeList ID="rtlxItems" runat="server" AllowMultiItemEdit="false"
        ParentDataKeyNames="ParentId" DataKeyNames="ChildId" ClientDataKeyNames="xItemsId">
```

Comment: I get the following exception: `KeyNames collection length must match ParentKeyNames collection length.`

Comment: From the beginning I have always got this error when I have more than 1 key each in the `ParentDataKeyNames` and `DataKeyNames` attributes.

Comment: I haven't seen documentation allowing to specify more than one dataKeyName for tree list, other controls allow a comma seperated list.  your parentId and xItemsId, or Child ID need to be of the same field type, and that's about it.  So either use xItemsId as your datakeyname for that item, or use childID and change this code to use childId: rtlItem.GetDataKeyValue("childID")